# Testing a class with private constructor

Tags: java, junit

Im trying to come up with the best way to test a cache class that im currently using.... i would like to substitute ClientFactory below when this class is run in tests.... I like to leave the structure of the class as much as possible but since it has a private constructor im struggling to think of the best way to test it..

```
public class MyCache {

private final long TIME_OUT

private static MyCache instance = null;

private final HashMap<String, MyObject> cache = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();

private MyCache() {
}

public static MyCache getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyCache();
    }
    return instance;
}

public MyObject getDetails(String id) throws Exception {

    MyObject myObject = cache.get(id);
    if (myObject != null) {
        return myObject;
    } else {
        try {

            // want to be able to replace ClientFactory with test stub
            Client client = ClientFactory.createClient();
            myObject = client.getMyObject(id);

        } catch (NotFoundException nf) {
           .... log error
        } 

        return myObject;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Even with a public constructor, since createClient is a static method, it's very hard to mock it. Learn about dependency injection, don't use the singleton anti-pattern, inject a ClientFactory in the public constructor, make sure createClient is an instance method and not a static method.

Comment: I would also consider not reinventing the wheel. The cache isn't thread-safe (which might or might not be a problem), and there are ready-to-use caches available, in Guava, for example.

Comment: thanks for the comments.... appreciated

Comment: hey just coming back to this again, when you say 'inject a ClientFactory in the public constructor' .. there is no public constructor... do you mean pass it to the getInstance?

Comment: No. I mean that there should be a public constructor, and you should simply rely on the dependency injection framework to create a single instance of this class.

Comment: i want to only have one instance only though, having a public constructor hints that its no a singleton no?

Comment: btw, there is no dependency injection framework on the project im working on as yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot of things, but I think that from testing perspective Singleton-pattern is not a good choice.

1. If you are using *Mockito*, you should extract the `ClientFactory.createClient()` call into a package-public (default) function. Mockito can spy singletons: `spy(MyCache.class)`, and you can change the behavior of the extracted function. So you replaced the `ClientFactory`.
2. You can replace your `private` constructor with a package-public contructor, and also you need to extract function mentioned in the first solution. After these changes you can extend `MyCache` in the test class (without *Mockito*).
3. You can extract the functionality of `MyCache` into a package-public class, which is not singleton (but can't call from outside). You can test it nicely, and `MyCache` will be only a singleton wrapper of the extracted class.

I think reflection is anti-pattern, but I know that the default access modifier (the empty string) is also ugly a little bit.

A few words about your singleton-pattern. This is not bad, if you have only one thread, but if you are in a multi-threaded environment, you need this codes:

```
// you need volatile, because of JVM thread caching
private static volatile MyCache instance;

private MyCache() {}

public static MyCache getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronize(MyCache.class) {
            // yes, you need double check, because of threads
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new MyCache();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: I like the sound of option three but not quite sure... how id structure it... any pseudocode you could share

Comment: Your MyCache file will be the same, but constructor will be package-public and no getInstance function, and there will be a MyCacheWrapper class, which getDetails function calls its instance (MyCache) getDetails function, and getInstance function creates a new MyCache(). Is it ok or should i write the two files?

Comment: ok i think i get you.... i was also thinking or adding a setter method to this class ... might be simpler...what do you think?

Comment: maybe it's ok, but it shouldn't be public